# Gamepad connection using Pro Micro(ATMEGA32u4 + HC-05

Tags: arduino-leonardo, hc-05, arduino-pro-micro

I have been working on making a HID compatible Gamepad using Pro Micro and HC-05 module. I have successfully configured the class of HC-05 module to appear as an Input device(A gamepad) on my PC without changing the firmware of the HC-05. However, after the bluetooth device gets paired there is no option showing to connect to it. My question is how do I start the blutooth connection?

Note: The class of device [calculator](https://www.ampedrftech.com/) tells you the hex for the class of device you want to make.
[image]

Comment: you said that the device pairs successfuly and it is seen as a gamepad ... that means it is connected ... what option are you trying to find?

Comment: @jsotola For audio devices I have to explicitly press a connect button, even after the device is paired(for windows). Also I tried looking for the device in device manager but I couldn't find it there. Maybe I am missing something. I also tried sending a hex message on loop using the arduino but still nothing. The message was, "0xFD 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x55 0xAA" as I saw on a blog.

Comment: This link helps you to connect the Gamepad to the pc - https://mitxela.com/projects/bluetooth_hid_gamepad

Comment: @MojtabaJahaniDarestani I've actually tried that blog before. Unfortunately the RN42 firmwares available online aren't compatible with any of my three different HC-05s. And after seeing that I could alter the class of BT device from the base HC-05 firmware I thought maybe I won't have to flash another firmware and someone might have figured it out.